# JSF 2 Nested Composite Components Question

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I've read some articles about writing composite components in JSF 2 and even about defining nested composite  components, but I haven't found the example to defining a composite component that can accept an undefined number of sub-components.

I would like to be able to create a composite components that can be used in a similar manner to this:

```
<special:fieldGroup>
  <special:field name="x" value="..."/>
  <special:field name="y" value="..."/>
  ...
</special:fieldGroup>
```

Is there an example or explanation on how to achieve this using the new JSF 2 syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about custom components (read: Java classes extending `UIComponent`) or composite components (read: XHTML files utilizing `xmlns:composite`)?

Comment: @BalusC I meant composite components because that's what I read about. But I will gladly try the other method... Let me know which one you think is better.

Comment: It is perfectly doable with both :) I was just wondering because when you're developing an `UIComponent` class (as your original question title and body implies), it would almost automagically be taken into account, but when you're developing a composite component, it is indeed not automatically taken into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`<composite:insertChildren>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/composite/insertChildren.html) to specify the location where the children of `<special:fieldGroup>` are to be inserted.

```
<composite:implementation>
    ...
    <composite:insertChildren />
    ...
</composite:implementation>
```

You can just write the `<special:field>` composite component "the usual way". Therein you can have access to the parent and its eventual attributes by `#{cc.parent.attrs.xxx}`.

Comment: Yes, that is a good solution. But what if you want to leave the layout up to another composite (in this case `special:aCustom`)? In some cases you want to delegate the inner parts to another composite, to avoid a bloat within the xhtml, which calls the parent composite.